# How to get jQuery to recognize mouse over image once per hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

I am trying to animate a picture when the mouse hovers over it. I am currently using "animate.css" to get the animation. There are two problems:

1) How do I get jQuery to "fire" my script once per hover? For example, if I create an alert, the alert will fire several times (putting the mouse over and taking it off).

2) What is wrong with my current jQuery syntax? The animation does not play.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="CSS/stylesheet_test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/animate.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:500&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/test.js"></script>
    <title>Daryl N.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="nav-text"><span id="home"><a href="index_test.html">Home</a></span><span id="archive">Archive</span></div>
      </div>
      <div id="first" class="background">
        <div class="align-vert"><img id="me-pic" src="./images/me.jpg" alt="A picture of me is suppose to be here" style="width:240px;height:240px;" class="me-border animated bounceIn"><span class="daryl animated bounceIn">Hi, I'm Daryl</span></div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/test.js"></script>
      <div id="second" class="background">
        <p class="align-vert">This is my personal website</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#me-pic').hover(function()
  {
    $(".bounceIn").toggleClass("bounce");
  });
});
```

My CSS

```
body,html
{
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container
{
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
}

.background
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.align-vert
{
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.me-border
{
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  vertical-align:middle
}

.navbar
{
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav-text
{
  color: #a3a3a3;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
  #home
  {
    margin-right: 50px;
  }

    #home:hover
    {
      color: #777777;
    }

    #home a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active
    {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: inherit;
    }

  #archive
  {
    margin-left: 50px;
  }

    #archive:hover
    {
      color: #777777;
    }


.daryl
{
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #FFF;
}
 #first
 {
   background: #2C2D45;
 }

#second
{
  background: #354677;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/animate.css) for animate.css

Could my CSS files cause a conflict?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you didn't show a CSS. what is a class `bounce`?

Comment: Please see my updated post.

Comment: i'm not really sure the problem you have but you can try mouseenter instead of hover and see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JS, I would instead use the *mouseenter* and *mouseleave* event handlers. Based on your explanation, this should serve nicely. It will fire exactly once when the mouse enters the div, and once when it leaves.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#me-pic').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(".bounceIn").toggleClass("bounce");
  });
  
  $('#me-pic').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(".bounceIn").toggleClass("bounce");
  });
  
});
```

Comment: The `.hover()` method, when passed a single function, will execute that handler for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. This allows the user to use jQuery's various toggle methods within the handler or to respond differently within the handler depending on the event.type

Comment: This does not seem to work for animate.css. I tried your method with an alert and it works. There seems to be something special about animate.css that prevents the effects from firing properly. Thanks for the help!